# Why is "while" used in this Weighted Quick Union implementation from Princeton

Tags: java, algorithm

As a part of my "back to the basics" trip I am looking at this method and I'm either missing something embarrassingly obvious, or `while` operator is not needed here:

```
// Return component identifier for component containing p
public int find(int p) {
    while (p != id[p])
        p = id[p];
    return p;
}
```

The full source is [here](http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/15uf/WeightedQuickUnionUF.java.html).

It looks like it can be as simple as this (and the whole function is rather pointless):

```
public int find(int p) {
    return id[p];
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not actually.

It will walk the array from pointer to pointer until the pointer equals the element id.

Example:

```
id = [ 2 0 3 3 ]
```

Then, `find(1)` would do something like:

```
id[1] = 0 != 1
id[0] = 2 != 0
id[2] = 3 != 2
id[3] = 3 == 3 => return 3
```

Comment: "When the wise man points to the sky, the simple man sees the finger..."

Comment: Aw, yes, now I realize that I started counting from 1

Answer (score 2):

Given `// id[i] = parent of i`, this loop finds the topmost ancestor, which is considered the component identifier. Otherwise, plain `id[p]` is the parent of `p`, and your statement will be correct only for `p` being the said topmost ancestor.

Answer (score 0):

private int[] id;    // id[i] = parent of i

thats at the top of the desciption so id[p] is NOT the same as the while loop